# c# Nmodbus ushort to uint32

Tags: c#, modbus

Я использую библиотеку nmodbus на с# для получения значения со счетчика по modbus tcp:

```
var factory = new ModbusFactory();
IModbusMaster master = factory.CreateMaster(client);
ushort[] inputs = master.ReadInputRegisters(1, 160, 1);
```

Проблема в том, что функция `ReadInputRegisters()` может считать максимально значение типа ushort. Как, используя эту библиотеку, считать значение типа uint32?

Comment: А он считывает правильно? В чем именно проблема? Судя по [документации](https://nmodbus.github.io/api/NModbus.IModbusMaster.html), нужной вам перегрузки метода нет. Пока ответ "никак".

Comment: Считывает правильно, если значение не превышает ushort.

Comment: Есть счетчик овеновский со значением типа uint32. Мне с него надо считывать значение по modbus. Пока ничего лучше чем использовать nmodbus на c# не придумал.

Comment: Все что может библиотека - в документации по ссылке выше. Я не вижу решения, которое вы ищете.

Comment: Я не понимаю, что такое "Number of holding registers to read" (3-е значение в методе). Максимально я смог его установить равным 24 для считывания uint32.  Вывод массива inputs[] выглядит следующим образом: 844
0
8
0
8
0
8
0
10
0
8
0
8
0
8
0
8
0
8
0
8
0
8
0

Comment: Ну, получается, что инты есть, но они разбиты по 2 шорта, так? Задача преобразовать это в `uint[]`?

Comment: Да, скорее всего так и есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Вывод массива inputs[] выглядит следующим образом: 844 0 8 0 8 0 8 0 10 0 8 0 8 0 8 0 8 0 8 0 8 0 8 0

Если проблема сводится к тому, чтобы преобразовать массив `ushort[]` в `uint[]`, то можно попробовать сделать это вот так.

```
ushort[] inputs = { 844, 0, 8, 0, 8, 0, 8, 0, 10, 0, 8, 0, 8, 0, 8, 0, 8, 0, 8, 0, 8, 0, 8, 0, };
Span<uint> span = MemoryMarshal.Cast<ushort, uint>(inputs);
uint[] result = span.ToArray(); // преобразовывать в массив необязательно, со спаном тоже можно работать
// если порядок шортов неправильный, то пройтись следующим циклом
for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
    result[i] = (result[i] >> 16) | (result[i] << 16);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
```

Вывод в консоль без изменения порядка

```
844, 8, 8, 8, 10, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8
```

Вывод с изменением порядка

```
55312384, 524288, 524288, 524288, 655360, 524288, 524288, 524288, 524288, 524288, 524288, 524288
```

> Максимально я смог его установить равным 24 для считывания uint32

Если вам нужно только первое число, то достаточно указать 2 вместо 24.

Comment: Нет, число вообще другое в счетчике (на данный момент 57868288). При этом меняется только первое число при считывании - 844, остальные также 0 и 8. Видимо здесь какое-то преобразование нужно. А может, еще и счетчик сам врет.

Comment: @AlexeyFominykh добавил вариант с перемешиванием порядка.

Comment: @AlexeyFominykh `на данный момент 57868288` как вы его получили? `844` как по мне - больше похоже на правду и на правильное значение. Конечно, когда это число дойдет до 65536 станет ясно, где правильно, а где неправильно. То есть в этом случае если я прав, то будет `0, 1` в массиве.

Comment: Первое число верное. Огромное спасибо тебе! Могешь)